# How to Actually get the money

Tags: transactions

I have no idea on what lm doing l deposited  $50 to a gaming site and won a little so want to get some of my winnings back to my keycard savings account but l have no idea how to do this lll enclose a photo, the gaming place asks for a Wallet Address which l did and withdrew $40 to my Bitcoin Wallet Address but now l don't know what to do next how do l get it from now the Bitcoin Wallet to my actual Bank Account any help would be appreciated as lm so way outta what l need to do its all just so hard Regards Mark Brown [image]

Comment: Hello Mark, I'm not sure how anybody could help you, since we don't even know what site you're referring to. If you have issues using a commercial website, the most likely source of information would be the operator of said site. Please try to check their FAQ or contact their support.

Answer (score 3):

It **looks** as though you are not actually attempting to **withdraw** Bitcoin. Rather, it looks as though you have gambled with **dollars**, and are being asked how you would like to **withdraw** your money from the site. In this withdrawl, they are simply offering Bitcoin as **one** of their payout options.

Bitcoin is not something that can be 'withdrawn' in this regard; it is essentially a commodity that is exchanged between two people. You sell your Bitcoin to someone else who is willing to buy it at the agreed price.

With this '**Method: Bitcoin**' you are seeing, you are essentially being asked to private a public key address in which the owner of Joe Fortune would deposit the **equivalent market value** of Bitcoin into. It's essentially like being asked to provide a bank account number in order for Joe Fortune to deposit funds into.

One Bitcoin is currently worth `~$4,635` USD, so instead of getting a payment of `~$310` USD, you would get a payment of `~0.07` Bitcoin (BTC).

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin cannot be 'withdrawn' to a bank account, it is a separate currency, in the same way that you can't 'withdraw' Indian Rupees to US dollars without exchanging. To get 'real money', you need to exchange/sell your bitcoin with some person or exchange platform, and have them pay the money into your bank account.